# Arithmetic operator confusion

Tags: java, operators

Why I'm getting two different values while using the arithmetic operators for the same value of variables. I've just altered little bit my second program, which is resulted in giving me the different output. Could anyone please tell me why?

```
    int number=113;
 int rot=0;
 rot=number%10;
 rot*=100+number/10;
 System.out.println(rot);//333



    int number=113;
 int rot=0;
 rot=number%10;
 rot=rot*100+number/10;
 System.out.println(rot);//311
```

Comment: Btw sometimes, adding blanks between math operands can increase readability and make the formula clearer (for yourself too!). E.g. you could write `rot = rot*100 + number/10`.

Comment: adding parenthesis would make it even clearer though

Comment: parenthesis muddle simple expressions like these imho, simple arithmetic rules should be no problem to developers

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In the first part you compute

```
rot *= 100 + number/10
```

which is

```
rot = rot * (100 + number/10)
```

And in the second part:

```
rot = rot*100 + number/10
```

Note that multiplication and division goes before addition and substraction.

Answer (score 2):

the problem is that *= has different (lower) precedence than * and +

```
rot *= 100 + number/10;
```

is equavalent to

rot = rot * (100 + number /10);

operator precdence can be found [here](http://www.uni-bonn.de/~manfear/javaoperators.php)

Answer (score 1):

It seems like the problem is [operator precedence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operator_precedence).

What this means is that `num * 10 + 13` is treated like `(num * 10) + 13`, i.e. the () are automatically added according to the rules of the language.

The difference then, in your example, is that the first one means the following:

```
rot*=100+number/10;
// Is the same as this:
rot = rot * (100 + (number / 10));
```

Whereas the second one means the following:

```
rot=rot*100+number/10;
// Is the same as this:
rot = (rot * 100) + (number / 10);
```

Since the parenthesis are in different places, these probably evaluate to different numbers.

Comment: -1 - `rot*=100+number/10;` is NOT the same as `rot * 100 + number / 10;` and `rot * 100 + number / 10;` is NOT the same as `rot * (100 + (number / 10));`.  You got the right answer, but for the wrong reason.

Comment: @Stephen: Thanks, I've changed my answer to what I think is the correct one (just removed the second step, since it was wrong... not sure what I was trying to say with it).

Answer (score 0):

in the second code because of the high precedence of *. rot*100 will be calculated and to that (number/10) will be added so its (300 + 11 = 311).